# Setting element visibility by Switch button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I develop and android App in Kotlin and I have a switch button with ID `ShowArchived` and I want it to change visibility of an object, so that the object (with ID `ArchProjectList`) would be visible when it is checked, and invisible when it isn't checked.
As far as I know action of makin it visible/unvisible would be that

```kotlin
ArchProjectList.visibility = View.VISIBLE //making visible
ArchProjectList.visibility = View.GONE //making unvisible
```

But how to bind this instructions to the right states of switch button?
The only thing I was able to find was this:

```kotlin
 ShowArchived.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
         // do whatever you need to do when the switch is toggled here
    }
```

but the point is it covers only action when button is checked, and I need to take some action (make element unvisible again) when is become unchecked. How can I do that?

Comment: "but the point is it covers only action when button is checked," - no it doesn't. That's exactly the point of the `isChecked` parameter in the callback. It tells you if it's checked or not when it switches states.

Answer (score 0):

isChecked is a boolean, it will be true when the user switches the switch to on, and false when the user switches it to off. So you can do this

```
if(isChecked){
   ArchProjectList.visibility = View.VISIBLE //making visible
}else{
   ArchProjectList.visibility = View.GONE //making visible
}
```

Comment: You mean to simply put that in those curly brackets insteat of `_, isChecked->//do whatever you need to do when the switch is toggled here`?

So something like this:
```
ShowArchived.setOnCheckedChangeListener { if(isChecked){
   ArchProjectList.visibility = View.VISIBLE //making visible
}else{
   ArchProjectList.visibility = View.GONE //making visible
}
    }
```
Or something else?

Comment: No, you have to do it after the arrow symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

     val simSwitch:SwitchCompat=findViewById(R.id.ShowArchived)
     // we dont use compoundButton but we still have to declare it
     simSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked -> enableSim(isChecked) }
    
}
```

Whenever I click simSwitch it will run `enableSim` function. You want `ArchProjectList` to be on and off.

```
private fun enableSim(onState:Boolean){
        if(onState){
//            everything we put in xml file is View
            ArchProjectList.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            Log.i("test","Switch is on")
        } else{
            ArchProjectList.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
            Log.i("test","Switch is off")
            
        }

    }
```